# C++ XML Schema Code Generator

Tags: c++, xml, code-generation, xsd

We have XML files and we want to have C++ classes generated out of XML schema like we have it in .NET xsd.

Also the generated classes instance needs to provide appropriate XML by calling some methods.

Answer (score 1):

I use Liquid XML Studio, it does all of that as well as documenting everything

Comment: Liquid is nice, but the code-gen is a premium feature - have to pay for it

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Web Services here, then I would really suggest going with [gSOAP](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html).

If you are only interested in data bindings in C++, then [XSD: XML Data Binding for C++](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) by code synthesis is also a very good tool, they are pretty good about documentation too.

Comment: Recommend [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) which I use a lot and have helped to improve significantly to cover all W3C data binding patterns so we know it is very robust with any XML schema use.

Answer (score 0):

[Gslgen](http://legacy.imatix.com/html/gslgen/) is known to be a good code generator. It uses a simplified version of XML though.